# listen to chrome-extension events from window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a simple chrome extension and cannot find a way to:

- send an event from the chrome extension
- listen to the event on the active tab and react to it

is there any way to do this or is it considered bad practice?

I tried using the `window` object but the extension lives in a sandbox environment with its own window object

Comment: Have a look at content scripts in Chrome API.

Comment: thank you! unfortunately I already have but can't wrap my head around how to do it

Comment: Here's an example that does it https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/_archive/mv2/api/messaging